# Directory structure for a website (js/css/img folders)

Tags: web-development, css, javascript, images, content

For years I've been using the following directory structure for my websites:

```
<root>
  ->js
    ->jquery.js
    ->tooltip.js
    ->someplugin.js
  ->css
    ->styles.css
    ->someplugin.css
  ->images
    -> all website images...
```

it seemed perfectly fine to me until I began to use different 3rd-party components.
For example, today I've downloaded a datetime picker javascript component that looks for its images in the same directory where its css file is located (css file contains urls like "url('calendar.png')").

So now I have 3 options:

**1)** put datepicker.css into my css directory and put its images along. I don't really like this option because I will have both css and image files inside the css directory and it is weird. Also I might meet files from different components with the same name, such as 2 different components, which link to background.png from their css files. I will have to fix those name collisions (by renaming one of the files and editing the corresponding file that contains the link).

**2)** put datepicker.css into my css directory, put its images into the images directory and edit datepicker.css to look for the images in the images directory. This option is ok but I have to spend some time to edit 3rd-party components to fit them to my site structure. Again, name collisions may occur here (as described in the previous option) and I will have to fix them.

**3)** put datepicker.js, datepicker.css and its images into a separate directory, let's say /3rdParty/datepicker/ and place the files as it was intended by the author (i.e., for example, /3rdParty/datepicker/css/datepicker.css, /3rdParty/datepicker/css/something.png, etc.). Now I begin to think that this option is the most correct.

Experienced web developers, what do you recommend?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I always create a lib directory for third party components, you really don't want to be changing third party libraries unless it is strictly necessary.

Go with the 3rd option.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of separating things by file type, which feels arbitrary to me, I organize files by how developers will use and think about them. I break things into a few basic categories:

```
myapp/
  ui/ # or "www"
    lib/ # third-party
      jquery/
      sugarjs/
      backbone/
      underscore/
    app/ # application logic
      main.js
      router.js
      views.js
      models.js
    style/ # all presentation
      main.css
      buttons.css
      icons/
        add.svg
        log.png
      img/
        logo.png
        signup.png
    components/ # standalone bundles of html/css/js, if necessary
  server/ # or "api" (all server-side logic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Option #2 is not practical and dangerous too as you'll have to re-apply all your changes (and hence might forget some) when you upgrade your 3rd party libraries. This is surely a big no no! Options #1 and #3 each have advantages and disadvantages. So I usually go for a combination of both.

My solution is to use Option #1 for my files and use Option #3 for 3rd party libraries.

Example:

```
<root>
  -> js
    -> jquery.js
    -> main.js
  -> css
    -> reset.css
    -> style.css
  -> img
    -> img1.jpg
    -> img2.jpg
  -> lib
    -> someplugin1
      -> original folder/file structure of this plugin
    -> someplugin2
      -> original folder/file structure of this plugin
```